# dictate when .wav file on userform plays automatically

Tags: excel, wav, vba

I am struggling to figure out the method to get the Windows media player control on my userform to run automatically when I want it to. I've set the control on the userform and linked a .wav file to it. It can be set to play automatically when the UF opens or upon clicking the play button as I'm sure you all know.

However, I want the sound to play depending on the selection of another control on the form or possibly upon unloading the form via command button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Any help would be greatly appreciated.` - What have you actually tried to get it to do work?

Comment: Show your code that plays the wav when the form opens.

Comment: There is no coding work involved in getting the wmp control to play upon the userform opening, at least not in 2013. You can set the control to play automatically from the properties window which occurs upon open; the alternate is clicking the control to play the file.

I have been searching for something like, on command button click that will be shared with other users, so the `.launch url` method would not work as the users would not have this file on their drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some exploring with the vba method list that auto populates after the decimal, I discovered it's an extension of `.controls`

e.g. `WindowsMediaPlayer1.Controls.Play`
This works the same way if hiding the control on a worksheet as well bu addressing the `.sheet` first. Though this still didn't give me what I wanted due to the .wav file not being embedded in the workbook but rather a URL on the WMP control. The easiest way I found around this was to save the .wav file on a shared drive or SharePoint that the users have access to.

not sure why that was such a difficult ask for people much more experienced than myself with all those rep points. Gotta love the down votes also as if I didn't specify I'm looking for the method to launch the .wav. As in I did not know and could not find the verbiage/script to get it to play at will.